# georeferenced JPEG images not intalling in QGIS correctly

Tags: qgis, imagery

I am trying do add georeferenced aerial images (jpg files) to my QGIS. They do not install properly. I either get a grey rectangle or bands of colour (mostly blue) that appear where the image should be.

Also, if I solve this problem, I then need to install all the images. Is there a quick way to insert multiple images from the host file?

Further info following comments:
I am using QGIS2.0.1
I have attached a screenshot of what the image looks like after adding to QGIS. A screenshot of the properties (style) layer.

[image: Distorted image layer]
[image: Properties (style)layer]

Comment: Can you include a screenshot of the Properties -> Styles tab of the layer? Otherwise it is hard to tell what goes wrong on your side.

Comment: What kind of JPEG image? What does gdalinfo show for a representative image? Which version of QGIS?

Comment: Virtual raster can help you to insert several jpg files as one layer. See gdalbuildvrt

Comment: Can you add a screenshot of the layers metadata? Or give a download link, or upload a sample file somewhere?

Answer (score 1):

If you can open a lot of .jpg files press `"add raster layer"` then filter to .jpg files and select all with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd> . Unless you want to merge them look at @ Zoltan comment or use `"Raster -> Miscellaneous -> Merge"`